# Exercise in calculus of variation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I need a hint on this exercise in Calculus of Variation.

Let $X=\{u\in C^{1}(-1,1)\cap C[-1,1]:u(\pm 1)=0\}$ and consider the length and the area functionals $F,G:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{equation*}
F(u)=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1+u'(x)^{2}}dx
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
G(u)=\int_{-1}^{1}u(x)dx
\end{equation*}
For a fixed constant $v>0$ consider the minimum problem:
\begin{equation*}
\min\{F(u):u\in X \ \text{such that} \ G(u)=v\}
\end{equation*}
Assuming its existence we compute its solution.

Given $\phi$, $\psi\in C^{\infty}_{c}(-1,1)$ define $H:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $H(\epsilon,\tau)=G(u+\epsilon\phi+\tau\psi)$. Show that there exists $\psi$ and a function $\epsilon\mapsto\tau(\epsilon)$ such that $H(\epsilon,\tau(\epsilon))=v$ for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't understand, what does the second question has to do with the first? Consider asking a new question for it. But first, I believe this is imprecise. You ask to show that there is a $\phi$ and at the same time a $\tau$ for every $\phi$? Makes no sense to me, could you clarify?

Comment: Yes actually I've made a mistake. The question is: show that exist $\psi$ and a function $\epsilon\mapsto\tau(\epsilon)$ such that $H(\epsilon,\tau(\epsilon))=v$ for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: Isn't it just the implicit function theorem?

Comment: Yes thank you so much. I only have to choose a function $\psi\in C^{\infty}_{c}(-1,1)$ such that the directional derivative of $G$ on the point $u$ in direction of $\psi$: $\delta G(u,\psi)\neq 0$ and then I can apply the implicit function theorem, correct?

Comment: $\partial H/ \partial \tau (0, 0) = G'(u)$. Why is it nonzero? Then you can apply the IFT

Comment: Because it is an hypotesis of the ICT

Comment: What is ICT, please?

Comment: Because it is in the hypotesis of the IFT

Comment: the hypotesis of the theorem is the following (referred to our case):$\exists H_\tau(0,0)^{-1}=\bigg(\frac{d}{d\tau}G(u+\tau\psi)\lvert_{\tau=0}\bigg)^{-1}$

Comment: Yes, we need it. But why is it true in our case?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your last question

Comment: We need, in order to apply the IFT, that $G'(u) \neq 0$, where the derivative is in the sense of Fréchet. But we do not know that this holds, a priori. But who is $G'(u)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106833/discussion-between-danilo-gregorin-and-andrea-stanghellini).